# Can I load directly an object that I want, jumping others in the serie, for pickle files

Tags: python, pickle

I want to unpickle a object that  I pickled behind many others. I would like to know if I can load this directly.

I pickle several objects as:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(A_object, f)
    pickle.dump(B_object, f)
    pickle.dump(C_object, f)
```

Now in another code, I want to load C_object, so I do:

```
with open(filename, ‘rb’) as f:
    pickle.load(f)
    pickle.load(f)
    C_object=pickle.load(f)
```

it works however in my real code I have to many objects and the procedure of passing for all the previews objects takes to much time. Could I load directly the C_object?

I search for something like:

```
with open(filename, ‘rb’) as f:
    C_object=pickle.load(f, 2)
```

Avoiding me to load each previous object and making my code so more efficient.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need this object specifically, why not pickle it in a separate file and load that? Or change the pickle order so that the objects that you want the most often are at the top?

Comment: You want shelves https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not something supported by `pickle`, this is the purpose of the `shelve` module.

It lets you manipulate a file of pickled objects as a dictionary: you can store things by associating them with keys, and get them through these keys.

Here's a dummy example:

```
import shelve


class Foo:
    pass


with shelve.open("test.shelf") as shelf:
    shelf['a'] = Foo()
    shelf['b'] = Foo()
    shelf['c'] = Foo()


with shelve.open("test.shelf") as shelf:
    foo_c = shelf['c']
```

You may have a look at the [documentation for `shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) for more features.